# Is there any way to ask for a interactive input after a condition is met?

Tags: interactive

Something like the example below, which I want to test whether you are eligible to enter a number before you actually enter this number

```
(defun foo (x)
  (cond (condition (progn (interactive "nEnter your number: ") ...))
        (t (message "You cannot enter a number right now!"))))
```

Comment: You can pass an expression that evaluates to the list of arguments to `interactive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this, as suggested by @DoMiNeLa10.

```
(defun foo(x)
  (interactive (list (if condition
             (read-number "Enter your number: ")
               (error"You cannot enter a number right now!"))))
  (message "%s" x))
```

Comment: Perfect, an example is exactly what`s needed for a beginner like me! Thank you!